# php with form alert box

Tags: php, forms, submit

I would like this `php` form to pop up an alert box on completion or if there is error.
What do I need to add or change to this to make that happen, or is that added `javascript`?

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['comment'];
    $from = 'From: Contact Form'; 
    $to = 'email@domain.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hello';


    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
    }

?>
```

Comment: *"or is that added javascript?"* yes - an pop up alert box is js not php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page that would display the error, you would add javascript to pop up the message using the alert() function. You could use php to conditionally output this javascript. Oy vey.

Example:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    <?php if ($error) { ?>
    window.onload = function() {
        alert('<?php echo $error?>');
    }        
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```

Something like that.

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for, i didnt understand how to call on my php in the js..thanks!

Comment: Glad this helps. Don't forget to accept if this works for you :D

Answer (score 4):

To do this you will need to add some more technologies, specifically Javascript and AJAX.

PHP is a sever-side language, which means that by the time the browser is rendering the page PHP has completed running your code.

Comment: ok so would I just do another if statement in js and have something similar to whats in my php?

Comment: You could connect your form to a javascript function by adding an `onSubmit:` to your form. Which would then validate the form, and if there is an error produce the alert, otherwise have it submit the form. Give Google a search for 'Javascript Form Validation'. It should get you in the right direction.

Comment: alright perfect thank you, ill mark it as a correct answer once it allows me to ha

Comment: Thanks Blake, if you have any other questons my contact information is in my profile, feel free to email me.